# Module exports object passed by value and not reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can call ReactDOM.render only after the element with id react-container has loaded, therefore I must have it in the document.ready, but doing it like I did in the snippet, just returns undefined and does not update its value after the overlay object is properly set in the document.ready function.

code:

```
var Overlay = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { show: false };
    },
    render: function() {
        if (!this.state.show) {
            return null;
        }
        return(
            <div>Hello</div>
        );
    }
});

var overlay;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    overlay = ReactDOM.render(
      <Overlay />,
      $('#react-container')[0]
     );
});

module.exports = overlay;
```

Moving the ReacDOM.render function outside this file is problematic, because I am not transforming (.jsx -> .js) the file where I want to use it.

Comment: Where you are using this `overlay` component?

Comment: Just move your script after `#react-container`, no need of `$( document ).ready`.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks, idk why I didn't think of doing this.